# NLTK: feature reduction after vectorization

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk

I have extracted unstructured textual data from approximately 3000 documents and I am attempting to use this data to classify this document.

However, even after removing stopwords & punctuation and lemmatizing the data, the count vectorization produces more than 64000 features.

A lot of these features contain unnecessary tokens like random numbers and text in different languages.

The libraries I have used are:

- tokenization: Punkt (NLTK)
- pos tagging: Penn Treebank (NLTK)
- lemmatization: WordNet(NLTK)
- vectorization: CountVectorizer (sk-learn)

Can anyone suggest how I can reduce the number of features for training my classifier?

Comment: Count vectorizer will always produce a huge amount of features for any kind of sizeable corpus. You should try to provide it with a vocabulary list in order to limit that. Making a good vocabulary list is itself a good problem to work on.

Comment: Exactly. The issue with this particular problem is that, for me, it lies in uncharted territory. So I'm not even sure about the words I should try to find

Comment: If you want to learn what makes words significant for identifying/classifying documents I would advice you to look into the `tf/idf` algorithm. It might even be what CountVectorizer uses internally for weighting, but if you have a good grip on how words are chosen, you should be able to make a list of most significant words from a corpus. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk

Comment: To expand a bit on my last comment, I have remembered a tutorial that uses sklearn and word count vectors ins the same way that you do, but couples it with tf idf to handle the amount of data. You might find help there: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-grid-search-text-feature-extraction-py

Comment: @ArneRecknagel I'm already performing the tf-idf transformation for preprocessing, As far as the list of most significant words are concerned, I don't think I have the insight at present for it. That may be something I can think of doing in the future once I've dived deep enough in this particular domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices here, that can be complementary :

1. Change your tokenization with stronger rules using regex to remove numbers or other tokens you are not interested in.
2. Use feature selection to keep a subset of your features that are relevant for the classification. Here is a demo sample of code to keep 50% of the features in data:

`from sklearn.datasets import load_iris`

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
import numpy
iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
selector = SelectPercentile(score_func=chi2, percentile=50)
X_reduced = selector.fit_transform(X, y)
```

Comment: The regex will definitely reduce the number of tokens that I have upon vectorization. But if I need to reduce the variables further, the SelectPercentile class should be the right way to go. Thanks for the input! Will update once the classifier is up and running